# Double clicking on map annotations

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, methods, mkmapview, double-click

I want to zoom in on an annotation after double clicking on it, but I cant seem to find a method in the developer documentation that does this, So how do I zoom in on a double clicked annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a custom Annotation that can detect double click. Subclass MKAnnotationView  and detect double click